# Move commit history between tfs instances

Tags: tfs

I am part of a very small team. We're thinking about trying the hosted tfs-service (tfspreview.com)
We're currently using tfs 2010 but neither of us is administrator on that machine.

Is it possible to "move" the commit-history (all I care about is code. Having the correct dates/users to the commits would be nice but is not required.)

Technically it would be ok for me to check out every commit of the old tfs and check that in into the new one. But I feel there has to be an easy way to do this...

Comment: Are you looking for: (a) a one-time migration of source code (including history) from one TFS instance to another, (b) a continuous automatic sync mechanism, (c) a manual but repeated sync mechanism, or (d) something else entirely?

Comment: I was looking for a "one-time-shot". I needed the history of the code but not the metadata of the commits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TFS Integration Tools is the only method I know of doing this, and it has limitations.

[Migrating from an On-Premises Team Foundation Server to Team Foundation Service Preview Using the TFS Integration Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj130558.aspx)

> What IS NOT migrated by the Toolkit
>
> - Exact check-in date/time (checkins are replayed)
> - Check-in notes
> - Labels
> - Permissions
> - Workspaces
> - Pending Changes
> - Shelvesets
> - File encodings
> - Subscriptions
> - Test Cases
> - Check-in policies
> - Reports
> - Team Portal / SharePoint
> - Process Templates
> - Work item queries
> - Builds
> - Warehouse data

Comment: Seems this is the correct "answer".. However it does not work for me. I am getting an error saying I'm not allowed to edit some of the data. Starting the migration results in about 400 conflicts...

Comment: I did it, it took a long time and is pretty badly documented. For me it was "go through all options" for some decisions, where I just could not put any meaning into the options and their explanation. Still, in the end, it kind of worked (comments slightly different, plus branching between projects seems to be pretty complicated).

Answer (score 2):

in the end I did this using [git-tfs](http://git-tfs.com/). I cloned (using `--no-metadata`, to not confuse the clone of the new repo after applying the commits) the old tfs-repo and extracted a patch serial. Next I cloned the new tfs-repo and applied the patch-serial. `git tfs rcheckin` "pushed" the commits to the tfs.

Drawbacks:

- now I have done every commit...
- every commit happend "right now"

So.. using this way I lost all the metadata of the commits (who did what and when) but I retained the code-history...